# Не запускается скайп: "на компьютере отсутствует api-ms-win-crt-runtime"

Tags: skype

Поясните,пожалуйста, почему перестал работать скайп? При запуске скайпа появляется сообщение, что на компьютере отсутствует api-ms-win-crt-runtime. 3 дня назад все было в порядке. Никаких новых программ установлено не было. Ничего не удалялось. Что могло произойти?

Comment: [тема в сообществе скайпа](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-XP-Vista-7-8-x-10/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll/td-p/4611045)

Comment: А при чём тут [tag:javascript]?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вероятно просто не нашлось подходящего тега

Comment: @Grundy, [tag:skype] 35 вопросов ;)

Answer (score 2):

скачай vcredist и установи его.
https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что можно тут в ответе разместить код vcredist. )